# OAuth2 : How to generate client id and client secret?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

Let's say I have a simple application.

How to set up OAuth2 to allow another application to access to some parts of my application.

For example, when devs want to use the Facebook API, they use the Facebook API User interface that generate Client id, client secret etc.

So, this is what i want my website do. provide client credentials when they request them.Not necessary by building an UI but programmatically (JAVA).

In other words, what is the stack behind the facebook API OAuth UI ? Is there a simple framework to set it up quickly and easily ?

thank you

Comment: As an example. **[Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/)** provides an API (`/api/client/create`) to register a client application. The API returns a JSON which includes a newly issued pair of client ID and client secret. Also, Authlete provides [Web Console](https://www.authlete.com/documents/cd_console) for developers to manage client applications, so you don't have to develop UI. The simplest Java example is [java-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of frameworks for setting up OAuth in a Java application. I would recommend having a look at [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/), for example.